# PIVOT statement error

Tags: t-sql, pivot

I cannot get working `PIVOT` over following data set

```
Machine   AtTime                     ValueString
-------------------------------------------------
3     2017-06-01 11:42:33.000         Start

3     2017-06-01 11:43:46.000         Stop

5     2017-06-01 12:42:33.000         Start

5     2017-06-01 12:43:46.000         Stop
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT Machine, TimeStart, TimeEnd
FROM
(
      SELECT  Machine, [AtTime], [ValueString]
  FROM [dbo].[DATA_ACTION]
)
) d
PIVOT
(
  MAX(AtTime)
  FOR [AtTime] in (TimeStart, TimeEnd)
) piv;
```

**Error**

> There is an error during converting data type nvarchar to datetime.

**Objective**

Get table like this

```
Machine  TimeStart                  TimeEnd
------------------------------------------------------------
3        2017-06-01 11:42:33.000    2017-06-01 11:43:46.000
5        2017-06-01 12:42:33.000    2017-06-01 12:43:46.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Valuestring:

```
create table data_action(Machine  nvarchar(50), AtTime datetime,ValueString nvarchar(50))
insert into data_action values (3,'2017-06-01 11:42:33.000','Start')
insert into data_action values (3,'2017-06-01 11:43:46.000','Stop')
insert into data_action values (5,'2017-06-01 12:42:33.000','Start')
insert into data_action values (5,'2017-06-01 12:43:46.000','Stop')


SELECT machine,start as [TimeStart],stop as [TimeEnd]
FROM
(
 SELECT  Machine, [AtTime], [ValueString]
  FROM [dbo].[DATA_ACTION]
) d
PIVOT
(
  MAX(AtTime)
  FOR [ValueString] in ([Start] , [Stop])
) piv;
```

The result is:

```
*---------*-------------------------*------------------------*   
|machine  |TimeStart                |TimeEnd                 | 
*---------*-------------------------*------------------------*      
|3        |2017-06-01 11:42:33.000  |2017-06-01 11:43:46.000 | 
*---------*-------------------------*------------------------*      
|5        |2017-06-01 12:42:33.000  |2017-06-01 12:43:46.000 |
*---------*-------------------------*------------------------*
```

Comment: I am not sure. I did in my sql server. It works properly.